# Application is not recognized by Game Center after iOS Certificate renewal

Tags: ios, certificate, game-center, renewal

I recently renewed my iOS Certificate and now one of my apps that has been on the app store and using game center will no longer let me sign in. When Game Center is trying to authenticateLocalPlayer I get GKErrorDomain Code=15 "The requested operation could not be completed because this applicaion is not recognized by Game Center". Also when I go to iTunes Connect I see on my app page in red "Leaderboard is not a member of a leaderboard set attached to version 2.0". I don't know what I am missing to get Game Center working again for my device. Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: In the sandbox or in production? Are you running the same build of your app after you renewed the cert, or are you running a new build signed by the new cert?

Comment: If i run in sandbox mode game center works fine. If i run in production then game center does not let me sign in. I tried using both the same build and a different build after I renewed the certificate.